# Trying to use freopen but for two different files

Tags: xcode, nslog, freopen

I am trying using `freopen()` to print to two different files.
is it possible?

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *docFile = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"sensordata.txt"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:docDir])
{
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:docFile contents:nil
                                   attributes:nil];
}
freopen([docFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
NSLog(@"GyroData: %f %f %f ",gyroData.rotationRate.x, gyroData.rotationRate.y, gyroData.rotationRate.z);


NSLog(@"DeviceMotion: %f  ",magnitude);
```

The second NSLog ( DeviceMotion...) should be saved in another file.

Any Idea?
thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What exactly is it that you expect to happen? What is actually happening and how does it differ from what you expect? If you expect that writing to `stderr` goes to two files at the same time, then, no, that's not possible in the way you mean.

Comment: If you want to do this then dump `NSLog()` and either write your own logging framework or use an existing one, like CocoaLumberjack: https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why you want to do it this way. Can't you just use `fprintf` instead? For objects AFAIK `NSLog` just calls `- (NSString*)description` which you can do yourself just as easily.

Regardless, here's (probably) how:

`NSLog` is most likely it's writing directly to underlying `STDERR_FILENO` file descriptor (fd). You can change the target of that fd using the `dup2` system call.

If you still want to work with `FILE*` functions it looks something like this (untested, error checking needed):

```
FILE *newlogfile = fopen([docFile fileSystemRepresentation], "a+");
dup2(fileno(newlogfile), STDERR_FILENO);
fclose(newlogfile);
```

You don't have to keep the pointer to the file because the descriptor is duplicated. The old `STDERR_FILENO` fd is closed automatically.

Comment: Actually, `NSLog()` uses [the ASL (Apple System Logging) facility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html).

Comment: @per Johansson
thanks a lot, I solved it with my own logging , I was trying till now everything.